# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink

Tags: node.js, backend

I have been trying for days to solve this error message that Postman returns to me.
I've already tried everything on the internet:
1). Permissions are authorized
2). I already ran Visual Studio Code as an administrator
3). I already deleted Node_Modules and Packagelock.json and then do npm install

{ "message": "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Santiago Felippelli\Desktop\ecomerce-back\public\images\images-1710255251125-18187900.jpeg'", "stack": "Error: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Santiago Felippelli\Desktop\ecomerce-back\public\images\images-1710255251125-18187900.jpeg'\n at C:\Users\Santiago Felippelli\Desktop\ecomerce-back\controller\productCtrl.js:232:15\n at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)" }

Context: I am using Node.js to make the back end of an ecommerce and my problem arises when uploading images to Cloudinary. Once I make the put, that error occurs.
What other option exists?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.